# including span in php array?

Tags: php, css, html

I'm still learning php, so I'm not entirely sure how to address..
I need to have an image and some text display in a php array. Currently, I'm using a span but it's not working properly- only one span is showing the image I've established in the stylesheet.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to achieve this, or if I've just missed an error?

[live site](http://blog.christaandivy.com/)

```
<div class="pagination">    
        <ul>
            <li><?php previous_post_link('<span class="left-arrow"></span> older posts'); ?></li>
            <li><?php next_post_link('<span class="right-arrow"></span> newer posts'); ?></li>
        </ul>            
    </div><!-- end pagination -->

#blog .pagination {
    background: url('img/arrow_left.png') no-repeat;
    height: 169px;
    width: 635px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-align:center;
}

#blog .pagination ul { 
    display:inline;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#blog .pagination ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 290px;
}

#blog .pagination .left-arrow {
    padding-right: 20px;
}

#blog .pagination .right-arrow {
    padding-left: 20px;
}


#blog .pagination .left-arrow span {
    background: url('arrow_left.png') no-repeat;
}

#blog .pagination .right-arrow span {
    background: url('arrow_right.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: the code is okay check the source if arrow_right has good extension and it is in same folder as arrow_left is.

Comment: @Robert The right arrow is in the same folder as the left, and I copy/pasted it's file name into the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your #blog .pagination shows the left_arrow.png as a background image. The #blog .pagination .left-arrow span and .right-arrow span are not showing because the extra span on the end means your need another span inside the span with that class name..

→ **Try this at the top:**

```
<div class="pagination">    
        <ul>
            <li><?php previous_post_link('<span class="left-arrow"><span> ... </span></span> older posts'); ?></li>
            <li><?php next_post_link('<span class="right-arrow"><span> ... </span></span> newer posts'); ?></li>
        </ul>            
    </div><!-- end pagination -->
```

Does the arrow show up now?

Answer (score 0):

```
 #blog .pagination .left-arrow span {
    background: url('arrow_left.png') no-repeat;
 }

 #blog .pagination .right-arrow span {
    background: url('arrow_right.png') no-repeat;
 }
```

This code will attempt to put a background image in a `<span>` that is inside a block with `class="right-arrow"`, which is not the same thing as `<span class="right-arrow">`.

I'm not sure why one of them is working though. If you name your classes like this it might work better: `#blog .pagination span.left-arrow` or  just `span.left-arrow`

Comment: No discernible changes were made; the right arrow is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem on you #blog is with the right arrow image. You have entered an incorrect source for the image.

If you correct  the image source, right arrow image will show.

Comment: The right arrow is in the same folder as the left, and I copy/pasted it's file name into the stylesheet.

Comment: But on your live site when I see the code using inspect element the url to the background image is invalid. The current url is [link](http://blog.christaandivy.com/wp-content/themes/theme/arrow_right.png/) which is incorrect, the correct url is [link](http://blog.christaandivy.com/wp-content/themes/theme/img/arrow_right.png), also notice you need to remove the slash from last.

Answer (score 0):

correct:

```
#blog .pagination span.left-arrow {
    background: url('img/arrow_left.png') no-repeat;
}

#blog .pagination span.right-arrow {
    background: url('img/arrow_right.png') no-repeat;
}
```